# C# and excel deleting rows

Tags: c#, excel

I want to write from my form (in C#) to an excel spread sheet and delete certain rows if blank.

I can write perfectly fine to a speadsheet and save it, but lets say the user entered data into row a1, a2, a3, and a4, I now want to delete all the rows in between a4 and a29.

All I need is to find out how to delete a certain range of cells.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it using a Range Object. I assume here that you are using Excel interop.

Let say you have your book open, then set the range then delete it 
It should look something like this

```
ApplicationClass excel = new ApplicationClass();
//Abrir libro y seleccionar la hoja adecuada aqui
//...

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cel = (Range)excel.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex];
cel.Delete();
```

Comment: I keep getting a type mismatch exception pointing to

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cel = (Range)excel.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex];

Comment: What you did worked, although it isnt doing exactly as i want. It did delete the values withing those cells within the range defined, but I was to actually get rid of that row alltogether so everything between a4-a39 is deleted or hidden, so it looks like..

a1
a2
a3
a4
a30
a31
a32

thanks for your comment, and I actually used that withing a function I need to use later so thank you for your input. greatly appreciated

Answer (score 15):

```
// Here is the answers to 
// 1. Delete entire row - Below rows will shift up
// 2. Delete few cells - Below cells will shift up
// 3. Clear few cells - No shifting

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
                  Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ResultFilePath);
                  ExcelApp.Visible = true;
                  Excel.Worksheet ExcelWorksheet = ExcelWorkbook.Sheets[1];

Excel.Range TempRange = ExcelWorksheet.get_Range("H11", "J15");

// 1. To Delete Entire Row - below rows will shift up
TempRange.EntireRow.Delete(Type.Missing);

// 2. To Delete Cells - Below cells will shift up
TempRange.Cells.Delete(Type.Missing);

// 3. To clear Cells - No shifting
TempRange.Cells.Clear();
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use this. İt's working ...

```
    _Application docExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application { Visible = false };
   dynamic workbooksExcel = docExcel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\mahmut.efe\Desktop\Book4.xlsx");
   var worksheetExcel = (_Worksheet)workbooksExcel.ActiveSheet;

   ((Range)worksheetExcel.Rows[2, Missing.Value]).Delete(XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);

   workbooksExcel.Save();
   workbooksExcel.Close(false);
   docExcel.Application.Quit();
```

For more information you can visit [this](http://labs.winshuttle.com/devnet/?p=120) web site

Comment: The web site referenced does not contain any content. Your answer is not wrong exactly, however, the answer listed above specifying the range member is cleaner. MSDN Provides great documentation on this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range_methods(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a cell (eg. A1) and find the entire row containing that cell as a range and then can delete the row.

```
excel.Worksheet sheet = (excel.Worksheet)excelWorkBook.Sheets["sheet1"];    
excel.Range cells = (excel.Range)sheet.Range["A1", Type.Missing];    
excel.Range del = cells.EntireRow;    
del.Delete();
```

The above given code will delete first row from sheet1

Answer (score 1):

To remove a row you need an only simple row of code as a follow

```
xlWorkSheet.Rows[NUMBER_ROW].Delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

using Microsoft.office.interop.excel delete rows using workseet range

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(srcFile);
        Excel.Worksheet workSheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range range = workSheet.Rows[2];
        
        range.Delete();
        
        xlWorkbook.SaveAs(dstFile);
        xlWorkbook.Close();
        xlApp.Quit();
```