# How to remove the word "Data" at the top of Excel Pivot Table generated by C# with Interop.Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, office-interop

I have the following example raw data table:

[image: Original Table]

And hope to make the following Pivot Table using C# and the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library:

[image: Desired Pivot Table]

I have written the following code to generate both the original table and the pivot table:

```
            string fileTest = "test.xlsx";

            Excel.Application app;
            Excel.Worksheet sheet;
            Excel.Workbook book;

            app = new Excel.Application();
            book = app.Workbooks.Add();
            sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)book.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            sheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Name";
            sheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Salary";
            sheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Hours";
            sheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Department";

            sheet.Cells[2, 1] = "Bill";
            sheet.Cells[2, 2] = 140000;
            sheet.Cells[2, 3] = 40;
            sheet.Cells[2, 4] = "IT";

            sheet.Cells[3, 1] = "Ann";
            sheet.Cells[3, 2] = 310000;
            sheet.Cells[3, 3] = 60;
            sheet.Cells[3, 4] = "Payroll";

            sheet.Cells[4, 1] = "Bob";
            sheet.Cells[4, 2] = 200000;
            sheet.Cells[4, 3] = 50;
            sheet.Cells[4, 4] = "IT";

            sheet.Cells[5, 1] = "Sam";
            sheet.Cells[5, 2] = 50000;
            sheet.Cells[5, 3] = 20;
            sheet.Cells[5, 4] = "Payroll";

            Excel.Range range = sheet.Range["A1", "D5"];

            Excel.Worksheet pivotSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)book.Worksheets.Add();

            pivotSheet.Name = "Pivot Table";

            Excel.Range range2 = pivotSheet.Cells[1, 1];

            Excel.PivotCache pivotCache = (Excel.PivotCache)book.PivotCaches().Add(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, range);
            Excel.PivotTable pivotTable = (Excel.PivotTable)pivotSheet.PivotTables().Add(PivotCache: pivotCache, TableDestination: range2, TableName: "Summary");

            Excel.PivotField pivotField = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields("Salary");
            pivotField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
            pivotField.Function = Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum;

            Excel.PivotField pivotField3 = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields("Hours");
            pivotField3.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
            pivotField3.Function = Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum;

            Excel.PivotField pivotField2 = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields("Department");
            pivotField2.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;

            Excel.PivotField dataField = pivotTable.DataPivotField;
            dataField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;

            pivotTable.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleLight16";

            book.SaveAs(fileTest);
            book.Close();
            app.Quit();
```

However, my Pivot Table has an extra row in the Pivot Table Header with the word "Data" in it:

[image: Resulting Pivot Table]

Is there a way I can remove this extra header? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Never really done work with excel, but couldn't you just delete the row before saving (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255166/c-sharp-and-excel-deleting-rows))?

Comment: @Hayden Doesn't work. It says deleting the first row will modify the pivot table, which isn't allowed

Answer (score 0):

Just unclick the Field Headers option under PivotTable Analyze ribbon.

[image]